# Log responses from apache httpClient

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, logging, apache-httpclient-4.x

I tried [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html) tutorial and enabled via logging.level ... = TRACE in yml.
But there are no logs for response, only for requests body and headers.
I looked in the apache code and didn't see the way where responses logs, only requests.

Is there a way to log apache httpClient responses via configs?
Could they be enabled only by yml and be readable?

Thank you,
Irina

Comment: Do u have a github project with you?

Comment: `log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=DEBUG` seems to be working. Please post your yml if it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

for v4 of the apache http components library, you need to set the `org.apache.http.wire` logger to `DEBUG` level as per [the apache http v4 wiki](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html):

Depending on which logging framework you are using, that could be done like:

Apache Commons Logging (set the system properties):

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

Log4j (in log4j.properties):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%c] %m%n 

log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

Logback (in Code):

```
((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire")).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

Logback (in `logback.xml` config file):

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="DEBUG"/>   
</configuration>
```